# how to manipulate with codeigniter

Tags: postgresql, codeigniter, insert

How I get my data array from view? and how to insert in my database?

my view, I try much code but still an error, sorry about my question and my bad English

```
<form role="form" action="<?php echo base_url().'potongan/validasi'?>" action="GET">
          <div class="box-body">
          <div class="box-header with-border">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-3">
            <label >NIM</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nim" id="nim" placeholder="NIM" value="<?php echo $nime ?>" readonly>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-3">
            <label >Nama Mahasiswa</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="namamhs" placeholder="Nama Mahasiswa" value="<?php echo $nim[0]->namamhs ?>" disabled>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-3">
            <label >Jurusan</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="jurusan" placeholder="Jurusan" value="<?php echo $nim[0]->jurusan ?>" disabled>
            </div>  
          </div>
            <br>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label >Kode Beasiswa</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control " name="kdbeasiswa" value="<?php echo $kdbeasiswa ?>" readonly>
            </div>

             <div class="form-group">
              <label >Keterangan</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control " name="keterangan" value="<?php echo $keterangan ?>" readonly>
            </div>

            <div>
              <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
                <tr>
                  <th></th>
                  <th>Kode</th>
                  <th>Deskripsi</th>
                  <th>Tahun Akademik</th>
                  <th>semester</th>
                  <th>Tagihan</th>
                  <th>Beasiswa</th>
                  <th>Terbayar</th>
                  <th>Potongan</th>
                </tr>
                  <?php foreach ($nim as $n): ?>
                    <tr>
                    <td>
                        <input type="hidden" class="form-control " name="id[]" value="<?php echo $n->thakad.$n->smtakad.$n->kdkeu; ?>" maxlength="3" >
                    </td>
                    <td><input type="hidden" class="form-control " name="kdkeu[]" value="<?php echo $n->kdkeu; ?>" maxlength="3" ><?php echo $n->kdkeu; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $n->deskeu; ?></td>
                    <td><input type="hidden" class="form-control " name="thakad[]" value="<?php echo $n->thakad; ?>" maxlength="3" ><?php echo $n->thakad; ?></td>
                    <td><input type="hidden" class="form-control " name="smtakad[]" value="<?php echo $n->smtakad; ?>" maxlength="3" ><?php echo $n->smtakad_view; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $n->tagihan; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $n->beasiswa; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $n->terbayar; ?></td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control " name="prosentase_bea[]" value="<?php echo $n->potongan; ?>"  maxlength="3">
                    </td>
                    </tr>
                  <?php endforeach ?>
              </table>
            </div>
            </div>
            <br>
              <button class="btn btn-info" style="float: right;">submit</button>
          </div>
          <!-- /.box-body -->
        </form>
```

my controller looks like this when I submit no data insert to the database and  error like

> Filename: C:/xampp/htdocs/tagihan/system/database/DB_query_builder.php
>   Line Number: 1498

```
$data = array();

    $count = count($this->input->post('device'));

        for($i=0; $i<$count; $i++) {

        $data[] = array(
        $thakad= $this->input->get('thakad'),
        $smtakad= $this->input->get('smtakad'),
        $kb = $this->input->get('kdbeasiswa'),
        $kk = $this->input->get('kdkeu'),
        $nim= $this->input->get('nim'),
        $pb = $this->input->get('prosentase_bea'),
        $status = 1,                  
        $user = $this->session->userdata('username'),
        $kt = $this->input->get('keterangan'),
        $curentDate = date("Y-m-d"));


}
$this->db->insert_batch('keu_beasiswapermhs',$data);
redirect('http://localhost/tagihan/potongan');
```

Comment: Your form method is get. And you are counting inputs from post method

Comment: sorry my mistake, I haven't edited it when I posted

Comment: it should be like this  $count = count($this->input->get('kdkeu'));?

Comment: What error did you get?

Comment: @ChristhoferNatalius If i use code like above  
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Array to string conversion

Filename: database/DB_query_builder.php

Line Number: 1592

Backtrace:

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\tagihan\application\controllers\potongan.php
Line: 86
Function: insert_batch

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\tagihan\index.php
Line: 315
Function: require_once

Comment: Which one is potongan.php Line: 86? You are trying to print array instead of string.

Comment: @ChristhoferNatalius in line 86 kode is  $this->db->insert_batch('keu_beasiswapermhs',$data);

Answer (score 0):

Make a habit using the proper MVC

VIEW

```
<form action="URL" method="post">
</form>
```

CONTROLLER

```
$this->model->function_name();
redirect('URL');
```

MODEL

```
function function_name(){
   $dataArr = array(
   'field_name'=>$this->input->post('form_input_name'),
   );
   $this->db->INSERT('tbl_name',$dataArr);
}
```

Comment: for insert repetitions, do I need a code like for or while or foreach?

Comment: @adit yes you create an empty array, need to iterate through the input and push each input to array, then you just have to do insert_batch('table_name', $arr)

Comment: @ChristhoferNatalius and error same like this  A PHP Error was encountered Severity: Notice Message: Array to string conversion Filename: database/DB_query_builder.php Line Number: 1592 Backtrace: File: C:\xampp\htdocs\tagihan\application\controllers\potongan.php Line: 86 Function: insert_batch File: C:\xampp\htdocs\tagihan\index.php Line: 315 Function: require_once

Answer (score 0):

You have fields like "namamhs" and "jurusan" that are not being put into the db.

You do not need for or while loops to insert data

**You are not assigning what fields in your db each posted item goes to.** Your controller has no idea where each value should be inserted. Do not use get, you should use post. Here is an example for your controller you can adapt to your form:

```
$data = [
        'url'     => $this->input->post('url'),
        'name'    => $this->input->post('name'),
        'genre'   => $this->input->post('genre'),
        'counter' => $this->input->post('counter'),
        'type'    => $this->input->post('type')
];
```

where 'url' is a field in your db that you are putting $this->input->post('url') into.
Next you check the values:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('url', 'url', 'required|trim');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('name', 'Name', 'required|trim|callback_trims');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('genre', 'Genre', 'required|trim');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('counter', 'Counter', 'numeric');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('type', 'Type', 'required|min_length[3]');
```

If the values pass the validation, inserting is simple

```
if( $this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
        echo validation_errors();
    }else
    {
        $this->db->insert('music', $data);
    }
```

You do not need batch insert. Just use insert

Answer (score 0):

Your $data array is empty...always check if array not empty before insert batch...that cause error DB_query_builder.php Line Number: 1498